# ctypes call GetProcAddress() failed with error code 127,but win32api.GetProcAddress successed

Tags: python, ctypes

When I call `GetProcAddress()` by win32api, I get the handle successfully but `ctypes` didn't.

The codes are:

```
from ctypes import windll
import win32api
KERNEL32 = windll.kernel32
h_kernel32 = KERNEL32.GetModuleHandleW('kernel32.dll')
print(hex(h_kernel32))

h_loadlib1=win32api.GetProcAddress(h_kernel32,'LoadLibraryW')
print(hex(h_loadlib1))
if not h_loadlib1:
    print("NtCreateThreadEx Failed:",win32api.GetLastError())

h_loadlib2 = KERNEL32.GetProcAddress(h_kernel32,'LoadLibraryW')
print(hex(h_loadlib2))
if not h_loadlib2:
    print("NtCreateThreadEx Failed:",win32api.GetLastError())
```

And the outputs:

```
0x77250000  
0x77266f80  
0x0  
NtCreateThreadEx Failed: 127
```

SYSTEM INFO:
windows7 64, python 3.43

Comment: You can use `kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32');` `LoadLibraryW = kernel32.LoadLibraryW`. You can pass this function pointer as argument in a call to `CreateThread` or `NtCreateThreadEx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a char string rather than the default Unicode string provided by python 3.x, as hinted by the [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation (the 2nd parameter is a `LPCSTR`, **not** `LPCTSTR` or `LPCWSTR`):

`h_loadlib2 = KERNEL32.GetProcAddress(h_kernel32,'LoadLibraryW'.encode(encoding='ascii'))`

Alternatively, you can pass a byte:

`h_loadlib2 = KERNEL32.GetProcAddress(h_kernel32, b'LoadLibraryW')`

Note: The above code won't work on a python 64-bit interpreter (the most significant 32-bit of the 64-bit module handle are zeroed). In this case you'll need to use `argtypes` and `restype` as [explained in the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) (for example by defining a 64-bit `HMODULE` type).

Comment: h_loadlib2 = KERNEL32.GetProcAddress(h_kernel32, b'LoadLibraryW')  works well, BUT I'm using a python 64-bit interpreter.

Comment: @zoumi: It doesn't work on my 64-bit box (Python 3.4 ; Win8.1). Tested with both interpreters (32 and 64-bit) and the above code doesn't work on the 64-bit one. What is the output of `import platform; platform.architecture()` on your interpreter?

Comment: @Neitsa, the OP is using `windll.kernel32`. Maybe some other module has assigned `windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress.restype` to a pointer type. Anyway, if the OP is just doing this to get an address to pass to `CreateThread`, then it's a needless waste of time. There's no reason to call `GetProcAddress` in ctypes code.

Comment: @eryksun: Yes, you're definitely right. Still a pleasure to have your feedback about ctypes and python!

Comment: @Neitsa------------>Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32------------->('64bit', 'WindowsPE')